# Firebase Admin SDK not removing claims

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I started to use Firestore Admin SDK mainly for user management.

The problem i have is that I can set custom claims but I cannot remove the claims (not one, not all)

```
Map<String, Object> newRoles = new HashMap<>();
userRoles.forEach((k,v) -> {
   for(var role : roles){
       if(k.equals(SecurityConfig.Roles.ROLE + role.getName())){
           break;
       }

       newRoles.putIfAbsent(k,v);
   }
});

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(userUid, newRoles);
```

This should keep only one claim / role in according to the call I make.

But even if i use

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(userUid, null);
```

It will keep the claims just like they are, nothing will be deleted, only added.

Using Springboot (java 11) & firestore admin sdk (latest version)

Do you have any idea on what i should try at this point?

No errors in the log / console / stack trace

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I am updating user 2 while authenticated with user 1

Comment: How are you checking the updated claims? Are you running `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(userId)` and checking the returned value? Or some other way?

Comment: @Hiranya first I do a login and get a new token and then I just decided it on jwt.io so the claims are still there

Comment: Please verify if the claims have been actually removed by running `getUser()` at the server-side. If that indicates the claims have been removed then the problem is in your client-side code.